# Any .NET API for RED5 Media Server or any other cross platform media server with .NET API?

Tags: c#, .net, api, open-source, red5

I need to implement a streaming Audio/Video Client in C# using RED5 Media Server. Can anybody tell me if there is any .NET API available for this???

Also, if there is no API for .NET available, then please guide if there is an open source, cross platform media server available that has a .NET API?

Please guide.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after surfing a bit, I haven't noticed a .NET server API for Red5, but I think you could use the open source Java API for Red5 [here](http://www.red5.org/). Then, [here](http://www.ikvm.net/devguide/net2java.html) are instructions to help you use the Java API in a .NET environment. I think this should be enough to get you pointed in the right direction. CHEERS!